# Send initial arguments from a Django view to Dash and read it outside layout

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I have an scatter plot on Dash. This scatterplot takes the values from SQL depending on the input parameter `id`. After querying the database with `id`, in case it is the first time it is accessed the given `id` element, it saves the x,y values in a csv.

Then, Dash reads the given csv and plots it.

Until here, everything works except that I am not able to read the value sent from the Django view.

My approach is the following one:

`views.py`:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def chart(request):
    id = request.GET.get('ID', None)

    if not os.path.isfile(f"{processed_path}/{id}.csv"):
    # Query SQL with id in case the output_variable for the given id does not exist and write the csv file
    context['dash_context'] = {'target_id': {'value': id}}
    return render(request, 'plots/chart.html', context)
```

`chart.html`:

```
{% load plotly_dash %}
{%plotly_app name="Genome" ratio=1% initial_arguments=dash_context}
```

`Dash application`

```
app = DjangoDash('Genome', id='target_id')
### Get id value passed to template <----
input_file = f"{id}.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
fig = px.scatter(df, x='x', y="y")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    dcc.Graph(
        id='plot1',
        figure=fig
    ),
])
```

Therefore, **my question is**: how can I read in the DjangoDash app the parameter that the user introduces in the url **before displaying the layouts**, which will be used to determine the input csv to read the x,y values in the layouts?

Comment: If you are passing simple values around the application and not full data sets I'd recommend using something like Redis to store and retrieve values.  I use Flask with Dash and Redis is a very reliable way to pass information between the Dash apps and the Flask endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Brady, that seems like a reasonable answer but I then have an additional question: how do you access the corresponding session data in redis in Dash, given the fact that you are outside a view and therefore you cannot access the `request` data freely?

Comment: Checkout this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70784905/17983531). You'll find your solution

Comment: Checkout this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70784905/17983531). You'll find your solution

Comment: Hi @SofiaDPG. I have tried that but whenever I put the same value in the div as the input parameter, the app never loads. It gets stucked in the loading screen. Did you do anything else besides what it's in your answer in order to make it work?