# Get Request in django-plotly-dash

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I am trying to pass args in get request to plotly app :
but I cannot retrieve the information.

my_webpage.html?value=1

code version: django-plotly-dash==2.0.0

views.py:

```
def my_webpage(request):
    return render(request, 'home/my_webpage.html', {})
```

my_webpage.html :

```
{%  extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    {% load plotly_dash %}
    <div class="{% plotly_class name='my_webpage' %} card" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
    {% plotly_app name='my_webpage'  ratio=10 %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

---

my_webpage.py :

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = DjangoDash('my_webpage', external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets )
app.layout =  html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),

    html.Div(id='page-content'),
    ])


@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              Input('url', 'search'))  
def display_page(params):
    print("model_view - display_page")
    parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(params)
    parsed_dict = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed.query)

    print(parsed_dict)
    page_content = params
    for i in parsed_dict.keys():
        page_content += f"{f}   {parsed_dict[i]} \n"
    print(params)
    return page_content
```

related links :
https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/issues/416

----UPDATE ----
Trying to use : initial_arguments

I am getting this error :
dash() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

```
def my_webpage(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id', None)
    context = {}
    context['dash_context'] = {'target_id': {'value': id}}
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'home/my_webpage.html',context)
```

my_webpage.html :

```
{%plotly_app name='my_webpage'  initial_arguments=dash_context ratio=10% }
```

my_webpage.py :

```
app = DjangoDash('my_webpage',  id='target_id', external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets )
```

related link : [Send initial arguments from a Django view to Dash and read it outside layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71439345/send-initial-arguments-from-a-django-view-to-dash-and-read-it-outside-layout)

Comment: Are you looking for this ... `value = request.GET.get('value')`

Comment: It looks like you want to want to add the `initial_arguments` parameter to the `plotly_class` template tag. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69414241/passing-a-django-database-pk-id-to-dash-app

Comment: @itsmehemant7 , no , I am looking for a way to retrive the get vars in the .py dash app. (my_webpage.py)

Comment: @Nealium  , could be, but I am still getting an error. I am using  django-plotly-dash==2.0.0

Comment: @user3505444 from what I'm seeing you **wouldn't** add `id` as a parameter to the function, you'd just use it in the Dash function.. and you **wouldn't** use it as a normal variable, you'd just place it in a string `'pk'` and Dash just recognizes it- it's very odd

Comment: I am not sure I follow, adding - when I print(context), I see the url get variable.

Comment: @itsmehemant7 if you write an answer in the form :  context['dash_context'] = {'target_id': {'children': id}}   - app.layout =  html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='target_id',children=',', title="#"),
  -  @app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              Input('target_id', 'children'), )  - the value is sent to the children callback